# Android Screen resolution Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I developped an android game, i created a gui box like this and added a matrix to resize this gui to differents screen resolutions, Here is the code:

```
float resolutionWidth = 800.0f;
float resolutionHeight = 480.0f;

void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(Screen.width / resolutionWidth, Screen.height / resolutionHeight, 1);
    GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 240f, (Screen.height / 2) - 170, 731, 447), "", WelcomeUI.customStyles[0]);
}
```

The problem that it's not resizing when i change the screen resolution. I don't understand what the problem
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: "This means that your OnGUI implementation might be called several times per frame (one call per event). For more information on GUI events see the Event reference. If the MonoBehaviour's enabled property is set to false, OnGUI() will not be called."

Comment: @marco-acierno is this a magic spell or what? I have read it twice but I haven't noticed any effect. Maybe it's wrong phase of moon now :D

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

Your code is a total mess. I don't think it's not resizing. I think it just doesn't do what you want.

Let's see what's going on:

1. ```
   GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(Screen.width / resolutionWidth, Screen.height / resolutionHeight, 1);
   ```

   You can thing of setting `GUI.matrix` as of setting a new coordinate space. In your case it's a coordinate system in which point (0, 0) is a left top corner of the screen, and point (resolutionWidth, resolutionHeight) is a right bottom corner of the screen. Which looks logical.
2. ```
   GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width / 2) - 240f, (Screen.height / 2) - 170, 731, 447), "", WelcomeUI.customStyles[0]);
   ```

   And this is completely wrong. You are now in a coordinate system which doesn't depend on actual screen resolution. But you are using `Screen.width` and `Screen.height` which do not have any sense here. A screen middle point right now is (resolutionWidth / 2, resolutionHeight / 2). Also, the size of your box is 731×447 which covers almost all the "model" screen. Something wrong here also.

## Example

Here's a short example for you:

```
float resolutionWidth = 800.0f;
float resolutionHeight = 480.0f;

public void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(
        new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
        Quaternion.identity,
        new Vector3(
            Screen.width / resolutionWidth,
            Screen.height / resolutionHeight,
            1.0f));
    Rect boxRect = new Rect(
        resolutionWidth / 2.0f - 240f, resolutionHeight / 2.0f - 170,
        480, 340);
    GUI.Box(boxRect, "");
}
```

Comment: Hello Sergey Krusch;
Thanks a lot for your help but i don't understand how do your put the  values in the code 480 and 340 how do you change them? thanks

Comment: What do you mean "how"? Type it using keyboard... As an option